# Proper use of Char**

Tags: c, char, getline

I am new to C and came across a Char**, for example in the getline function. I have found several topics regarding this type but none of it explained how to actually use it. I understood the differences between Char[], Char* and Char**, but how can I access the content stored in a Char**?

Could someone explain that to me? Thanks in advance!! :)

So, for example i am trying to use the getline function to extract single lines from a file and to store them:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(myfile,"r");
size_t fsize;
char **string;
ssize_t bytes_read =0; 
while ((bytes_read = getline(string, &fsize, fp))>0) {
// How to handle the content of string now? Is every line from the File stored in the Char** now?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost always when a function asks for a `char**` or a `**` in general, you're expected to give it the address of a pointer variable. In this case the address of a `char*`. The address of operator is `&`, thus you should call `getline` like this:

```
char *string = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
while ((bytes_read = getline(&string, &fsize, fp))>0) {
    // use string here...
}
free(string);
```

There are of course exceptions to the rule of `**` functions wanting an address of, but `getline` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `getline` it requires the memory address at which to store the memory address of the first character in the line you've read.

I.e. it needs a pointer to a pointer or a `char**`.

Your string will be stored in `*string`.

Of course you can get this information from the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) :).